# PHP SimpleXML get value from Object

Tags: php, simplexml

have a question regarding obtaining a value from a simpleXML Object. So firstly, I do this

```
$data = $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children()->ExecuteQueryResponse->pdomOutput->recipient->attributes()->email;
var_dump($data);
```

And that returns the following

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "myemail@email.com"
}
```

I need just the email address from this.  So I then proceed to do this

```
$this->response = (string)$data[0];
var_dump($this->response);
```

Now I would expect the above to return just the email address, but instead, it returns everything, including the type e.g.

```
string(26) "myemail@email.com"
```

I can easily get the email address from this using something like preg_match, but surely this is not the way to go?  Is it not possible to get the value without the type?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean type? Did you try and use echo instead of var_dump?

Comment: I was actually returning the whole value, and it didnt like me doing that without echoing it out (because of ajax).  Seems to work now thanks

Comment: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is doing what it's suppose to do, it's showing you the type and length and the content of the variable. While echo "just" shows the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to have the string, SimpleXML has the `__toString()` [function for SimpleXMLElements](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php). So with your code this would be:

```
$data = $xml->children('SOAP-ENV', true)->Body->children()->ExecuteQueryResponse->pdomOutput->recipient->attributes()->email;
$this->response = $data[0]->__toString();
```